# Result returned after running a script for a second time, undefined error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, undefined

This is a javascript meant to be a part of chrome extension. It should print out id when I press the add button.
What it does, though, is I have to press add TWICE to have the id appended where I want it to ( I use this instead of alert)
When debugging, it says that bookmarkBarID is undefined... I suppose this is the error but I dont know how to fix it. Please help
here is the whole code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var bookmarkBarID;
function getBM(){
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(tree){ 
bookmarkBarID=tree[0].children[0];
}); 
}



function CreateNewItem()
{
$('#submit').click(function (){
getBM()
console.log(bookmarkBarID);
$('.bookmark').append(bookmarkBarID.id);
})
}

    </script>
    </head>
<body onload="CreateNewItem();" style="width:1200px">
<div class="bookmark"></div>
  <input type="text" value="enter url here" id = 'urlLink' />
  <input type="text" value="enter Name title" id='linkName'/>
  <input type="text" value="" id='folderName' />
  <div><button id="submit">Add</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.bookmarks.getTree` is an *asynchronous* function, which means that it runs at the same time as your other code. The function finishes *after* the rest of your code executes. To use the function's results, you need to give a callback function that will be called with the results. In this case, you need to move `$('.bookmark').append(bookmarkBarID.id);` into the callback function:

```
function getBM(){
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(tree){ 
bookmarkBarID=tree[0].children[0];
console.log(bookmarkBarID);
$('.bookmark').append(bookmarkBarID.id);
}); 
}



function CreateNewItem()
{
$('#submit').click(function (){
getBM();
})
}
```

Note: you should use `$(document).ready(CreateNewItem);` instead of `onload` (assuming that you are using jQuery).

Comment: Thank you! Does it mean that every time I want to operate with bookmarks (I intend to use this script for searching specific folder id and creating links and folders inside it), I have to run the whole function again, or I have to run this function, finding all objects I want, and the passing to the next function(manipulating the results, creating folders). Is there a third way?

Comment: You can call `chrome.bookmarks.getTree` at any time, with any valid callback. Each time you call it, the callback given will be called once with the result (unless there was an error).

Comment: What I want to do is find a folder and its id when the script begins, so I can use the id to create links and folders inside this folder. I have to look through all folder names inside a given folder, to find the one I need. Once I do this, though I dont need to do it again, so I want to run chrome.bookmarks.getTree once...

Comment: Well, you can set a global variable (like you did) to the result. Then, all you need to do is check if the variable is defined: `if(bookmarkBarID != undefined){/*do stuff*/}`.